# Syntax error on __construct, works if I use ClassName as constructor signature

Tags: php, constructor, syntax-error

When I create and instance of this class I get the error

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '__construct' (T_STRING), 
expecting variable    (T_VARIABLE) on line 9.
```

This is how I create the instance:

```
    function controller_from_str($controller_name)
    {
        $controllers_namespace = 'MVCBP\\Controllers\\';
        $controller = $controllers_namespace 
            . $controller_name . 'Controller';

        return new $controller();
    }
```

It works if I change `__construct()` to `UserController()`. I use PHP 5.4 on Windows 7. Is this the expected behavior?

Here's my class:

```
<?php
namespace MVCBP\Controllers;

use MVCBP\Core as Core;
use MVCBP\Models as Models;
use MVCBP\Repositories as Repos;

class UserController implements Core\ControllerInterface
{
    private $UserRepo;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->UserRepo = new Repos\UserRepository();
    }

    public function Index()
    {
        echo '<h1>User</h1>';
    }

    public function Create()
    {
        //TODO: if GET/POST
        $user = new Models\User();
        /*var_dump($user->getDb());*/
        render_view('User/Create');
    }

    private function CreateGet()
    {

    }

    private function CreatePost()
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: There is nothing wrong with this code, looks like something terribly wrong with php installation

Comment: A brick wall then. Any suggestions for debugging this?

Comment: @GabrielSmoljár: Is there anything before this class? Or is it in its own file?

Comment: @MadaraUchiha The class is in it's own file which contain nothing more than what I pasted.

Comment: look like missing "function", `public __construct()`... maybe you enabled a system cache, like APC?

Comment: Laxus I'm using WampServer, don't think it has such a thing. But yes I did have that incorrect syntax earlier.

Comment: then you need to clear the cache

Comment: sure https://gist.github.com/anonymous/5233529

Comment: https://gist.github.com/gabbsmo/5233539

Comment: there is the possibility that the error that you are viewing is a cache page of your browser.. are you already clear it?

Comment: cleared it just now, but the error remains

Comment: I get the feeling you are looking into the wrong file. Because line 9 doesn't match with the above code.

Comment: The problem was not even close to what I described in the question. A constructor in a subclass somewhere was malformed.

PHP errors </3

Comment: Before  return new $controller(); try echoing $controller to see what you are trying to construct. Maybe it is the $construct string that is mulformed or at leastyou can diagnose the origin of error.